# Can we add a new tag for budget / budgeting / expenses?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

These may need to be linked to money, but I would never think to look for that tag when searching.

If people think we should add the new tags, should there be something different for budgeting than for money? I'm not sure if all of the items in money (teaching your kids about, etc.) are the same as budgeting. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Posts that should get the proposed tag, instead of `Money`:

[Can we afford to have a baby?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/can-we-afford-to-have-a-baby)

[What are important legal and financial steps for new parents?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/what-are-important-legal-and-financial-steps-for-new-parents)

[What factors should you consider when deciding how much to pay a babysitter?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/231/what-factors-should-you-consider-when-deciding-how-much-to-pay-a-babysitter)

[Is it better to get an infant car seat or a convertible?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/756/is-it-better-to-get-an-infant-car-seat-or-a-convertible)

[Are modern cloth diapers really cost efficient compared to disposible diapers?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/752/are-modern-cloth-diapers-really-cost-efficient-compared-to-disposible-diapers)

[What are the biggest expenses for a new baby?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/what-are-the-biggest-expenses-for-a-new-a-baby)

These are about parental budgeting, not about money as it relates to kids. For instance, " [How do we teach a pre-schooler about money and shopping?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/how-do-we-teach-a-pre-schooler-about-money-and-shopping) " This other category has lots of questions as well, but they really do differ.

And then we have this - it belongs in both categories, I think: [Should adults pay rent if they live in their parents' home?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/220/should-adults-pay-rent-if-they-live-in-their-parents-home)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Let me play the devil's advocate, and see what votes and comments this triggers:</sub>

**We don't need separate tags for money questions.** When we created the "money" tag and its synonyms, the intention was to bundle everything that is somehow related to money.

During the 15 months that this site has been active, we have only managed to collect a total of 13 questions so we get **less than 1 money-related question per month.** It would not really be an improvement to split these few questions into separate tags with even fewer questions in each.

Instead, we could certainly **add all the suggested new tags as new synonyms for the existing "money" tag.** Also, if you [do a search for [finance]](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) you will get the "money" tag, so it's already possible to search for tags even though they are really just synonyms.

Comment: Structure matters. If the site gets larger, it will matter, and if it does not, then it's irrelevant. They are different subjects, even if some of the words used to describe them happen to be the same.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sometimes I take a particular concept and multiply it by a thousand; if it still makes sense after being scaled up, then the idea is okay. So, to make these tags scale, we might need several more: *parents-finance, childrens-finance, budget-and-expenses,* and perhaps even more?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was the [finance](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag.  However, that has been made into a synonym with [money](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money).

I don't think its wrong to have those two linked, however, if we do want to make a distinction between planning costs related to parenting and teaching children about money, I think it would make much more sense to link [finance](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) with a new [budget](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) tag, rather than leave [money](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and [finance](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) as synonyms.

This would necessitate going through the [money](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money), and evaluate which need the [budget](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) tag instead of, or in addition to, the [money](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) tag.  Fortunately, it is not a very big list.

Before we make such a change, though, I'd want to give the community a bit of time to chime in.  Also, it would help quite a bit if you could compile a list of questions that you think should be tagged as [budget](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget) (or whatever the final decision as to what the tag should be called may be).

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.